# Is it possible to send prompt message to Huggingface chat role "system"?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I'm following the Quickstart guide below for building an LLM chatbot on my Snowflake db however I'm using Huggingface instead of OpenAI.

https://quickstarts.snowflake.com/guide/frosty_llm_chatbot_on_streamlit_snowflake/index.html#5

The code below is what I currently have in my prompt.py file, It is a message stating how Huggingface should interact with the user, this message is used in the function `get_system_prompt()` at the bottom of the prompts.py here:

https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/sfguide-frosty-llm-chatbot-on-streamlit-snowflake/blob/main/src/prompts.py#L15C6-L47

The function `get_system_prompt()` is called in the main app file... now this is where I believe the issue is.  Openai has a 'system' role that uses the `get_system_prompt()` function... but huggingface does not have this role when I try I get "Internal Error"
From what I can see in the huggingface chat doc it doesn't seem to be an option, only user or assistant: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/chat_templating

For reference, the main app file looks like and this is where it's calling the `get_system_prompt()`: (this except this is using OpenAI and I'm using Huggingface):
https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/sfguide-frosty-llm-chatbot-on-streamlit-snowflake/blob/main/src/frosty_app.py#L13

This is the huggingchat library I'm using to access huggingface: https://github.com/Soulter/hugging-chat-api/tree/master/src/hugchat

Error message I see:

> File "/Users/Desktop/SnowChatbox/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 534, in _run_script
> exec(code, module.**dict**)

> File "/Users/Desktop/SnowChatbox/LLM_Chatbox/streamlit_app.py", line 79, in
>
> st.write(response)

> File "/Users/Desktop/SnowChatbox/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/metrics_util.py",
> line 396, in wrapped_func
> result = non_optional_func(*args, **kwargs)

> File "/User/Desktop/SnowChatbox/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/streamlit/elements/write.py",
> line 259, in write
> stringified_arg = str(arg)

> File "/hugchat/message.py", line 228, in **str**
> return self.wait_until_done()

> File "/hugchat/message.py", line 194, in wait_until_done
> self.**next**()

> File "/hugchat/message.py", line 149, in **next**
> raise self.error

> File "/hugchat/message.py", line 100, in **next**
> self._filterResponse(a)

> File "/hugchat/message.py", line 85, in _filterResponse
> raise ChatError(f"Server returns an error: {obj['message']}")